# Express $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ in Rectangular Form

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

*"Express $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ in rectangular form."*

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (complex numbers), we have defined
\begin{equation}
\sin (z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
\end{equation}
I believe this is the polar form. Wikipedia helps out, by stating that
\begin{align}
\sin(x + iy) = \sin (x) \cosh (y) + i \cos (x) \sinh (y) \\
\cos(x + iy) = \cos (x) \cosh (y) - i \sin (x) \sinh (y)
\end{align}
However, how would one derive this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens when you take the right-hand-side, convert to exponentials, and simplify?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $z = x+iy$ where $z$ is now expressed in Cartesian coordinates. Then use the expression given to you for sine, $$\sin(x+iy) = \frac{e^{x+iy}-e^{-(x+iy)}}{2i}$$ and use a bit of algebra to get your result. It may also help to expand $$\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$ and see how you can make it become the LHS.